# Segmentation Fault QPainter

Tags: c++, pointers, opengl, segmentation-fault

I get a segmentation fault when I try to create a QOpenGLContext. My code is as follows:

```
if (!m_context) {
    m_context = new QOpenGLContext(this);
    m_context->setFormat(requestedFormat());
    m_context->create();
}
```

m_context is declared as

```
QOpenGLContext *m_context;
```

under private

The class inherits from QWindow and QOpenGLFunctions

```
class DisplayWindow : public QWindow, protected QOpenGLFunctions
```

In the constructor of the class m_context is set to 0.

Why does this segmentation fault occur?

Comment: On which line does it happen?

Comment: @molbdnilo m_context = new QOpenGLContext(this);

Comment: where is the rest of the code?

Comment: And you are sure that `this` is a properly created, valid object at the time?

Answer (score 0):

The problem most likely occurs in the code you didn't show.

[This](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qopenglfunctions.html#details) explains how to do what you want. You need to set the surface type with `setSurfaceType(OpenGLSurface);` :

```
MyGLWindow(QScreen *screen)
  : QWindow(screen), QOpenGLWidget(parent)
{
    setSurfaceType(OpenGLSurface);
    create();

    // Create an OpenGL context
    m_context = new QOpenGLContext;
    m_context->create();

    // Setup scene and render it
    initializeGL();
    paintGL()
}
```

Comment: I set the surface type in the constructor with setSurfaceType(QWindow::OpenGLSurface); but I create the QOpenGLContext in another function.